# Embedded visualforce page get truncated at the end while shown from IE9, but works fine in chrome with default page resolution

Tags: visualforce, css, browser, embedded

grid shown from Chrome:
[image: c]
grid shown from IE9 :

[image: i]

is there any solution to show the datatable automatically adjust to the salesforce default page size, and what is the mechanism of doing this?

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales_Grid" id="thePage"   >
 <style>

.odd
{ background-color:white;
}

.even
{  background-color: white;
}

.tooltip1:hover{  
            box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px 0 #a1b4bf;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;  
            width: 16px;  
            height: 15px;     
            background-position: right;  

        }  
.tooltip1{  
            box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px 0 #a1b4bf;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;  
            width: 16px;  
            height: 15px;  
        }

.tableClass{
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 1040px;
    font-size: 10px;
    }

th {
    border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #e1f1f7;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height : 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color:#e1f1f7;
    text-align:center;
}
td {border-collapse: separate;
    border: 1px solid #a1b4bf;
     border-spacing: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
     text-align:center;
    font-size: 11px;
     box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px 0 #a1b4bf;

}

th:first-child {  
    border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #e1f1f7;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 144px;
      font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color:#e1f1f7;
} 
td:first-child {  
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e1f1f7;

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 144px;

     font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;

}
th:nth-child(2) {  
    border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #e1f1f7;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 110px;
      font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color:#e1f1f7;
} 
td:nth-child(2) {  
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e1f1f7;

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 110px;

     font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;


}

th:nth-child(16) {  
    border-collapse: separate;
     border-spacing: 1px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color:transparent ;
} 
td:nth-child(16) {  
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #e1f1f7;

    overflow: visible;
    width: 16px;
     font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;

}
</style>

 <apex:form id="theForm" rendered="true" >  
  <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock"  >    
     <style>
            .headerStyle {
                font-size:12px;
               background-color:red;
            }
        </style>

  <div  style="width:1000px;height:40px;text-align:center;middle;">
   <apex:actionFunction name="SaveK" action="{!SaveK}" />
    <apex:actionFunction name="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
          <apex:commandButton value="Save"  oncomplete="triggerBlurEvents();" onclick="this.value = 'Saving...'"  id="saveButton"  style="display:none" />
 <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" id="cancelButton"  onclick="this.value = 'Cancelling...'" reRender="thePageBlock" style="display: none;" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Add New"  onclick="this.value = 'Adding...'" id="AddMoreButton" action="{!AddMore}"  style="width:60px; height:25px;"  /> 
   </div>                 
  <div style="text-align:center;width:955px; height:250px;overflow:auto;">    
            <apex:dataTable value="{!records}" var="k" id="theDataTable"  rendered="{!records.size>0}" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass" > 


               <apex:column >
          <apex:selectList value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Product__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="show();"  style="border-left:3px solid;border-left-color:red;
    font-size: 11px;height:22px;" >
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!ProductNames}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
        <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c.Fields.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Product__c.Label} </apex:facet>
       </apex:column> 

           <apex:column id="theColMatrix">
          <apex:selectList value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_Matrix__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="show();" id="Matrix" disabled="{!IF(ISNULL(k.Id) ,false, true)}" style="font-size: 11px;height:23px;"  >
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!Matrix}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
        <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c.Fields.Abv_Core_KAM_Matrix__c.Label} </apex:facet>
       </apex:column>    
   <apex:column styleClass="tooltip1" title="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_January__c}"><div style=" color:{!IF(AND( NOT(ISBLANK(k.Abv_Core_KAM_January__c)),k.Abv_Core_KAM_January__c<0) ,'red','')};text-align: center;">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_January__c}" id="January" > 
                  <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"   showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="AddMoreButton" 
                       /> 
                       </apex:outputfield>
                    <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c.Fields.Abv_Core_KAM_January__c.Label} </apex:facet>
               </div> </apex:column>

                <apex:column style="border: 1px solid #a1b4bf" styleClass="tooltipclass" title="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_December__c}"><div style=" color:{!IF(AND( NOT(ISBLANK(k.Abv_Core_KAM_December__c)),k.Abv_Core_KAM_December__c<0) ,'red','')};text-align: center;">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_December__c}" id="December" >
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"  showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="AddMoreButton" 
                       /> 
                       </apex:outputfield>  
                    <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c.Fields.Abv_Core_KAM_December__c.Label}</apex:facet>
             </div> </apex:column>

             <apex:column style="border: 1px solid #a1b4bf;"  styleClass="tooltipclass" title="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_Total__c}" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_Total__c}" id="Total" style="background-color:transparent" >

                       </apex:outputfield>  
                    <apex:facet name="header">{!$ObjectType.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Sales__c.Fields.Abv_Core_KAM_Total__c.Label}</apex:facet>
            </apex:column>

             <apex:column rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(k.Id) , false , true)}">
                 <apex:commandButton value="X" action="{!Del}" rerender="thePageBlock,delpopup" rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(k.Id) , false , true)}"  style="color:red;font-weight:bold;width:16px; ">
                  <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!k.Id}" assignTo="{!del_Id}"></apex:param>
                 </apex:commandButton>
                  </apex:column>    
                  </apex:dataTable> 
 </div>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Including your VisualForce page, including any styling you may have will possibly help people figure out what your issue could be.

Comment: hi @BarCotter i have edited the question with the VisualForce page code

Comment: All your widths are using pixels which could be the cause of it. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285058/css-percentages-or-pixels) to see if it helps.

Comment: hi everyone, very sorry, the second screenshot was from IE9,from a different system with smaller screenspace and not from IE8 and  and while including an inline visualforce page in account page layout , it shows differently from different browser and different screen resolution, whereas my requirement is that the inline VF will automatically adjust to the salesforce default page size of the Account

Answer (score 3):

It is likely a css style or DOM incompatibility on IE8.  I would recommend upgrading to a more current version of IE, since salesforce is discontinuing support for IE8 and earlier starting with the Summer 15 release.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getstart_browser_overview.htm

There are numerous known issues reported regarding IE8, after they stop support, it is very unlikely they will ever get resolved.

Comment: Also, if you're still using IE8, you are no longer setting security updates from Microsoft. Do you want an Enterprise-level nightmare on your hands?

Comment: Hi @JimRae  very sorry, the second screenshot was from IE9 ,from a different system with smaller screenspace and not from IE8 and while including an inline visualforce page in account page layout , it shows differently from different browser and different screen resolution, whereas my requirement is that the inline VF will automatically adjust to the salesforce default page size of the Account

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, very sorry, the second screenshot was from IE9,from a different system with smaller screenspace and not from IE8 and while including an inline visualforce page in account page layout , it shows differently from different browser and different screen resolution, whereas my requirement is that the inline VF will automatically adjust to the salesforce default page size of the Account